# Using hg convert to convert git repo to old svn format

Tags: git, svn, format, mercurial, mercurial-convert

According to the following post:

http://davidvg.com/2011/12/07/converting-a-git-repo-to-svn

a git repo can be converted to an svn repo using `hg convert`. This works for me, however, the resulting svn repo is to modern for me. The db/format number for the resulting svn repo is 6 (svn 1.8+). I need it to be 4 (1.6+), an older version of svn that is. Is there a way to specify for hg convert to convert to a specified db/format number?

Or, is there another way for me to convert my git repo to svn db/format 4 (1.6+)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a current version of Subversion to dump the repository into a version-agnostic format (`svnadmin dump`), then use the older version of Subversion to load that dumpfile into a new repository (`svnadmin load`).

Otherwise, I would suggest finding older versions of the hg & git based tools that support that older version of Subversion.